# Is it possible to set the output audio sample rate for a video file created using AVMutableComposition and AVAssetExportSession?

Tags: avfoundation, avasset, avassetexportsession, avmutablecomposition, sample-rate

I'm using `AVMutableComposition` and `AVAssetExportSession` to combine a silent MP4 video with a WAV audio file. The basic steps are:

- Create `AVAsset`s for the video and audio
- Add tracks to the `AVMutableComposition`
- Add each `AVAsset`s first track to a track in the `AVMutableComposition`
- Create an `AVAssetExportSession` using `AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough`
- Export asynchronously

Everything works, but the audio sample rate of the resulting video file is always 44.1 kHz, regardless of the sample rate of the WAV file. Is there a way to set the audio sample rate of the video file that's created?